# Possible to add loading text to silverlight splash screen?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, silverlight, loading, splash-screen

I recently added a splash screen to a silverlight web app, and was looking to add another feature. My idea is to have a textblock display the name of the element that is currently being loaded. I've searched for a solution, but can't seem to find one anywhere. I would appreciate any help/ideas anyone may have. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: +1, it would be neat to know how to identify an object or item as it's loading like this.

Comment: Not completely of help to you (hence not posting as an answer) but because we use Prism, and have our application divided into modules, we can take advantage of the ModuleManager class and the ModuleDownloadProgressChanged event to update our loading screen with information on what module and how much progress has been made.